# Clean up the [check] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Though the [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/check) tag has a tag wiki excerpt stating that it's meant to be used for the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) library, there are many questions which are about "checking" something in general and don't fit the tag.

With over 800 questions to "check" over, could it *please* be burninated?

Comment: Out of 803 questions, [775 are not tagged c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/check+-c). o_O

Comment: +1 to burn it. The excerpt has already been edited to say it's a bad tag. Perhaps we should add a [tag:c-check] or [tag:check-framework] tag for the C questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Burnination Completed!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/check?sort=newest&pageSize=50)

<sup>(Estimated duration: 5 Hours.)</sup>