# Please [check] all questions with this tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, blocklist-request

The [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/check) tag: [60 questions, no usage guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/check), and just a hodge-podge of people wanting to *check* something.

No clear or useful purpose at all.

Burninate and blacklist it I say.

What say ye?

Comment: A burn is warranted. We normally hold back on blacklisting. Only if a burninated tag keeps being recreated a tag is added to the blacklist.

Comment: Looks like it has already been [burninated once](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251067/clean-up-the-check-tag).

Comment: "Fit for burnination: [check]"

Comment: He's making a list, he's [check]ing it twice, Gonna find out if a burnination is wise, Trogdor is coming to town.

Comment: Time to stop payment on our tag [check].

Comment: This tag is [check]mated.

Answer (score 8):

Some of these questions can be retagged:

- Questions about putting checks in checkboxes or checking whether they are checked can be retagged [checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checkbox).
- Questions about check constraints in databases can be retagged [check-constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/check-constraints).
- Questions about software verification techniques (check if this code works...) can be retagged [verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verification).
- I didn't see any current questions about [chess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chess) that are also tagged [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/check), but if any show up, the [chess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chess) tag should be sufficient.

Having at least these three separate usages indicates to me that it's time to stop payment on this [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/check) right away!

Answer (score 7):

I’ve taken care of the tag manually, including closing what needed closing.

I’ve also take care of [uncheck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uncheck), in the same vein.