# Re-burninate and blacklist [check]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, blocklist-request

The [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/check) tag [has re-appeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/check) in the last month after being successfully burninated twice: [~7 years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261573/3889449) ago and [~1 year ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397397/please-check-all-questions-with-this-tag). I think we should re-burninate and also *blacklist* it as it's just being misused as a random keyword and doesn't add any useful information to the posts.

Not sure why it wasn't blacklisted already as the second post linked above is tagged [blocklist-request](/questions/tagged/blocklist-request) and [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: "Time to check up on [check]"? :)

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine "Time to check up on [check]... again"

Comment: Burn completed, the blacklist needs employee intervention

Comment: Proceed to [check] out.

Comment: Trogdor wants his [check]

Comment: You can [check] out any time you want, but you can never leave.

Comment: We don't want to [check] it anymore.

Comment: Woah [check] out all those puns... someone grab one and edit the title if you want, I can't pick a favorite hahaha

Comment: I just cleared out a dozen more that were posted between Zoe's cleanup and Catja's blocklist update. That's the last we'll see of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This block is now active.

We reviewed this request and have written up some guidance text for the blocked tag:

> Please use a more specific tag to describe the subject of your question. For example, "checkbox", "check-constraints", "verification".

These suggestions came from [an answer to the prior request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397411/4548692) to block the tag.

[image: Screenshot of a tag warning on the ask question page telling the user that the "check" tag is not allowed along with the guidance text in the quote above.]